# How to rotate table-headline in Latex table

Tags: latex, pdflatex

is there a way to rotate the "Demo 1", "Demo2" and "Demo 3" headlines 90° in the following LaText table?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,10pt]{report}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
 & Demo1 & Demo2 & Demo3 \\
\hline
Person 1 & x &  &    \\
\hline
Person 2 & x &  &  x  \\
\hline
Person 3 & x & x &    \\
\hline
Person 4 &  & x &  x  \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. As [Dr. Andrew J. Page wrote on his blog,](https://web.archive.org/web/20130613223913/http://andrewjpage.com/index.php?/archives/24-Latex-tables-and-rotated-text.html)

> Put this at the top of your code:
>
> \usepackage{rotating}
>
> Simply to create a table with rotated column text use this code:
>
> ```
> \begin{tabular}{|r|r|}\hline 
> \begin{sideways}Paper\end{sideways} &\begin{sideways}Static\end{sideways} \\
> \hline
> HAR1994j & Journal \\
> SWRT1996c & Conference \\
> \hline
> \end{tabular}
> ```

Comment: Link seems to be broken and answer is useless without the link.

Comment: @Trilarion, you are right. However, it's the accepted answer so I cannot delete it :-(